# Minor Mode for tracking changes in a buffer

Tags: emacs

Is there a minor mode in Emacs that will highlight changes made to a buffer?  I'm picturing something like [highlight tails](http://blog.arithm.com/2008/04/12/highlight-tail-for-emacs/) without a timeout feature.  I would use highlight tails for this and change the timeout rate to be something huge, but the mode seems to consume a bit of CPU to do the timing (a feature I wouldn't use).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrackChanges) is usually your friend for things like this. Sounds like you might want highlight-changes-mode.

Answer (score 2):

In short, +1 for Timo's suggestion of highlight changes mode.

And without even resorting to EmacsWiki:

```
M-x apropos RET highlight changes RET
```

It's bundled with recent Emacs versions.